# Where Does Entity Framework 6 Get Connection String For Migrations?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm using EntityFramework 6 code first with migrations. I have two projects -- UI and BusinessLogic. UI is a .NET MVC web application with a dependency on BusinessLogic, which is a class library. WebUI has the  config section including connection string. BusinessLogic also has the following config section (with no connection strings provided) and contains the actual code first Migration classes:

`<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>`

In Package Manager Console when I run `update-database -ProjectName BusinessLogic` it somehow knows to use the connection string from my UI project.

In an attempt to understand how/why this was happening, I attached the debugger to the constructor of my DbContext class like this:

```
public MyDbContext() : base(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(CONNECTION_STRING_KEY, false))
{
  //--launch the debugger
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Now with the debugger launched and a breakpoint in the DbContext constructor, I can evaluate `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` which yields:

`C:\\someRepoLocation\\Source\\BusinessLogic\\bin\\Debug\\`
This seems to indicate that the current app domain is BusinessLogic.

However, evaluating `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile` yields:
`C:\\someRepoLocation\\Source\\UI\\tmpD442.tmp`

So the current app domain is BusinessLogic, but it is using some .tmp configuration file in the root UI folder? Wat?

**Can anyone explain how/why this works without having a connection string providing in the app.config of BusinessLogic (where the Migrations exist)?** I was expecting I'd have to set a connection string in the BusinessLogic class library's app.config -- but I'm happy not to do this if this is the expected behavior. Looking forward to hear what is the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through some testing of my own, I've discovered that the config that is used during an `update-database` call is the currently set start-up project.

In my case, I set up a console application to do some batch work, and while debugging through the seed, I noticed the same behavior as you noted.  Swapping the start up project is what changes the active configuration.